# Adding UTC time to my countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, clock, countdown

I recently was searching after a countdown script that count down to a specific day, hour and minute and reset again after it reached the time.

Now a week later i see a major issue in the script. The countdown is based on local time and this is a problem.

I want to have the countdown based on the UTC time and not the local pc time.
Anyone that can help me with this because i'm not sure how to do this. I made also a clock script that i use and there i could say ".getUTC..." but i have no idea how to implement that in this script because i picked it up from the internet.

I'm not very good in javascript/jquery and i'm still learning a lot. I can mostely understand the scripts but i miss the lack of writing it myself so it would be very nice if you could edit the script so it's based on the UTC time and tell me a bit about it so i can learn from it. I really would appriciate that !

Thanks a lot,
Jens

```js
var EVENTDAY = 1; // monday
var EVENTHOUR = 22; //
var EVENTMINUTE = 42; //
    
function getRemaining( now )
{
    if ( now == null ) now = new Date();

    var dow = now.getDay();
    // the "hour" for now must include fractional parts of the hour, so...
    var hour = now.getHours() + now.getMinutes()/60 + now.getSeconds()/3600;

    // how many days from current day until event day?
    var offset = EVENTDAY - dow;

    // if event day is past *OR* if today is the event day but the event time is past...
    if ( offset < 0 || ( offset == 0 && EVENTHOUR < hour ) )
    {
        // we are past the event time in current week, so 
        // target EVENTDAY is next week:
        offset += 7; 
    }

    // so this date (day of the month) is the next occurrence of the event:
    var eventDate = now.getDate() + offset; 

    // and so then next occurrence of the event is at this time:
    var eventTime = new Date( now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), eventDate, 
                              EVENTHOUR, EVENTMINUTE, 0 ); 

    // this is how many milliseconds from now to the next event occurrence
    var millis = eventTime.getTime() - now.getTime();

    // convert milliseconds to days/hours/minutes/seconds:
    var seconds = Math.round( millis / 1000 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( seconds / 60 );
    seconds %= 60;
    var hours = Math.floor( minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    var days = Math.floor( hours / 24 );
    hours %= 24;
    if ( seconds < 10 ) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    if ( minutes < 10 ) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if ( hours < 10 ) hours = "0" + hours;
    if ( days == 1 ) {
 days = days + " day, ";
    } 
    else {
 days = days + " days, ";
    }
    // and return that formatted pretty:
    return days + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    
}

function tick()
{
    // this is the automatic once a second display:
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = getRemaining();
}
setInterval( tick, 1000 ); // specifies once a second

// here is a demo that allows you to test the function 
// by specifying a date and time in the <form> below
function demo( form )
{
    var t = form.theDate.value.split("/");
    var mn = Number(t[0]);
    var dy = Number(t[1]);
    var yr = Number(t[2]);
    var t = form.theTime.value.split(":");
    var hr = Number(t[0]);
    var mi = Number(t[1]);
    var sc = Number(t[2]);
    // so this is the test date/time that you specified:
    var test = new Date( yr, mn-1, dy, hr, mi, sc );

    // and here we call the master function and put its answer in the <form>:
    form.remaining.value = getRemaining( test );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using [Jcounter](http://devingredients.com/jcounter/)

**Change line 34 in the jquery.jCounter-0.1.4.js file**

```
serverDateSource: '/pathtofile/dateandtime.php', //path to dateandtime.php file (i.e. http://my-domain.com/dateandtime.php)
```

**in the dateandtime.php file**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0); error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Auckland");  // CHANGE HERE
// GMT +12
if (isset($_GET['timezone'])) {
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($_GET['timezone']);
} else {
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland");//CHANGE HERE
}
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone);
$dateAndTime = array("currentDate"=>$date->format('d F Y H:i:s'));
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($dateAndTime) . ')';
?>
```

**Then in you countdown timer file have it setup something like this:**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Auckland");//GMT+12 <--- CHANGE THIS
//Set your date and time below.
$day = date("D");
$hour = date("H");
if ($day=="Sun" && $hour>='9') {$date = date('d F Y H:i:s', strtotime('next Sunday 09:00:00'));}
else {$date = date('d F Y H:i:s', strtotime('this Sunday 09:00:00'));}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mycountdownname").jCounter({
            animation: "slide",
            date: "<?=$date?>", //format: DD month YYYY HH:MM:SS
            timezone: "Pacific/Auckland",
            format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
            twoDigits: 'on',
            callback: function() { console.log("Event Ended!")     }
    });
});
</script>
    <div class="mycountdownname">
    <div class="countdown-theme">
        <ul>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="days">00</b><i class="daysSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em>DAYS</span></p></li>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="hours">00</b><i class="hoursSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em>HOURS</span></p></li>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="minutes">00</b><i class="minutesSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em>MINS</span></p></li>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="seconds">00</b><i class="secondsSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em>SECS</span></p></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jC-clear"></div><br>
        <div class="jC-clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So i need to delete my script and use yours instead ?
Your script also do the exact same thing as mine ? Because i want the auto reset countdown for sure and i also have zero knowledge about php but i gonna try it out for sure.

Comment: i found this one to be the easiest to use and best for my needs, comes with a few themes aswell. but you may need to modify the css depending on the style you want

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `Date` here:

```
if ( now == null ) now = new Date();
```

You are almost there. Let's see some useful functions.

```
new Date().getTime()
```

will return the utc time.

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```

returns a string representation of the UTC timestamp.

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

returns the number of minutes to be added to get the UTC value. So, this is how you can get the UTC timestamp:

```
foo.setHours(foo.getHours() + (foo.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)).getTimezoneOffset()
```

where `foo` is a `Date` object.

So, this is how you get the UTC value of a date:

```
function getUTCDate(input) {
    return input.setHours(input.getHours() + (input.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)).getTimezoneOffset();
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
var now = getUTCDate(new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried some things but i don't fully understand what and where i need to add it in my script ? I think i need to use the last 4 code blocks you posted but i don't really understand where i need to put them.